# Find which direct property applied in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a list of properties I want to apply to a specific entity `mathematics: wd:Q395`. In this case:

```
instanceOf: 'wdt:P31'
subclassOf: 'wdt:P279'
```

The results are:

*Mathematics is instance of academic discipline and 
Mathematics is subclass of exact science and formal science*

Instead of making two different queries I would like to make them all at once:

```
SELECT ?field ?fieldLabel ?propertyApplied
WHERE {
      wd:Q395 wdt:P31 | wdt:P279  ?field. 
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      BIND("" AS ?propertyApplied)
}
```

**How can I know which property applied to fill the right column?** ( for example next to academic discipline I would like that it appears instance of)
[image]

I tried this but it looks weird and the results repeat themselves.

```
SELECT ?instanceOf ?subclassOf ?instanceOfLabel ?subclassOfLabel
WHERE {
      OPTIONAL { wd:Q395 wdt:P31 ?instanceOf. }
      OPTIONAL { wd:Q395 wdt:P279 ?subclassOf. }
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) or [`UNION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives):

```sql
SELECT ?field ?fieldLabel ?propertyLabel WHERE {
      VALUES (?predicate) {(wdt:P31) (wdt:P279)}
      wd:Q395 ?predicate ?field . 
      ?property wikibase:directClaim ?predicate .
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Ffield%20%3FfieldLabel%20%3FpropertyLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fpredicate%29%20%7B%28wdt%3AP31%29%20%28wdt%3AP279%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ395%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Ffield%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fpredicate%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

```sql
SELECT ?field ?fieldLabel ?propertyLabel {
     { wd:Q395 wdt:P31 ?field . BIND (wd:P31 AS ?property) }
      UNION
     { wd:Q395 wdt:P279 ?field . BIND (wd:P279 AS ?property) }
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Ffield%20%3FfieldLabel%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20wd%3AQ395%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ffield%20.%20BIND%20%28wd%3AP31%20AS%20%3Fproperty%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20wd%3AQ395%20wdt%3AP279%20%3Ffield%20.%20BIND%20%28wd%3AP279%20AS%20%3Fproperty%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)