# SPARQL: Find out which property is used for link

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

So I have the following query I would like to extend:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?p ?superItem ?superItemLabel
WHERE { 
  wd:Q146 (wdt:P279 | wdt:P31 | wdt:P361 )+ ?item.
  ?item   ( wdt:P279 | wdt:P31 | wdt:P361) ?superItem.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

If you run it in the [Wikidata Query Service](https://w.wiki/7yW) you can see an empty column. There I would like to have the Property responsible for that specific link. So either `wdt:P279` or `wdt:P31` or `wdt:P361`.

Is this somehow possible? And if yes how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51103215/7879193 ?

Comment: Thank you Stanislav, but as far as I understand it I am not able to find a connection like `Q146 --P31--> a --P279--> b --P279--> end`

Comment: If you need to output paths, I'd suggest to extract a subgraph via `CONSTUCT`, then load triples into Stardog, then use Stardog [`PATHS`](https://www.stardog.com/docs#_path_queries_2) queries.

Comment: you can't find arbitrary paths with standard SPARQL as @StanislavKralin already said. Either use some extension like the Stardog triple store provides, or use some graph database. In any case, you'd have to extract the outgoing subgraph of depth `d`

Comment: Subgraph: https://w.wiki/7ys

Comment: Or do you need just https://w.wiki/7zD?

Comment: Hey @Stanislav, https://w.wiki/7zD provides the answer I had with my question. But I think you are right that `CONSTRUCT` could be the way to go for me. If you write an answer based on https://w.wiki/7zD I will happily accept it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find which direct property applied in a SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103215/find-which-direct-property-applied-in-a-sparql-query)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to print property is used in a triple with the keyword `VALUES`.

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?p ?superItem ?superItemLabel
WHERE { 
  wd:Q146 (wdt:P279 | wdt:P31 | wdt:P361 )+ ?item.

  VALUES ?p { wdt:P279  wdt:P31  wdt:P361 }
  ?item  ?p ?superItem.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 50
```

Demo: http://linkedwiki.com/query/Find_out_which_property_is_used_for_link

Doc: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data